# How to remove the tag in XML using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, xslt, jaxb, marshalling

I'm using JAXB to convert java object into xml file.

In my XML file, I need to remove the tag  without using XSLT .

For example :remove the tag orders

```
<order_List>
  <orders>
    <orderid>12324<orderid>
  </orders>
</order_List>
```

Excepted result :

```
<order_List>
   <orderid>12324<orderid>
</order_List>
```

Comment: My advice on JAXB questions is usually to first search [Blaise Doughan](http://stackoverflow.com/users/383861/blaise-doughan)'s answers to other similar questions first, and then to await his reply to your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can suggest you "naive" approach.

The wrapper tag `orders` can be configured using JAXB annotation `@XmlElementWrapper`. So, you can create 2 models: one that contain this tag, another that does not. You can use the model that contains this tag to parse you data, then copy data to model that does not contain this tag and then use it to serialize.

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "index-annotations")
public class OrderList {
   private Collection<Integer> orderIds;

   @XmlElement(name = "orderid", type = Integer.class)
   public Collection<Integer> getOrderId() {
       return orderIds;
   }
}


@XmlRootElement(name = "index-annotations")
public class OutputOrderList extends OrderList {
   @Override
   @XmlElement(name = "orderid", type = Integer.class)
   @XmlElementWrapper(name="orders")
   public Collection<Integer> getOrderId() {
       return orderIds;
   }
}
```

Obviously this solution contains a kind of duplicate code, however it is probably better then configuring 2 schemas using XML because of compile time validation of annotations validity.