# JAXB Marshalling Java Object to XML with custom Elements

Tags: xml, xslt, jaxb, marshalling

Hi I am using JAXB Marshalling and I am getting following as my xml output

```
<catalogentries>
<catalogentry>
    <type>Product</type>
    <sequence>1.0</sequence>
    <partnumber>Product_H|||DAL|||CPCC05R2400JB32</partnumber>
    <parentgroupidentifier>Combo Memory</parentgroupidentifier>
    <manufacturerpartnumber>CPCC05R2400JB32</manufacturerpartnumber>
    <manufacturer>Spansion</manufacturer>
</catalogentry>
</catalogentries>
```

but I wanted my output like

```
<CatalogEntries>
<CatalogEentry>
    <Type>Product</Type>
    <Sequence>1.0</Sequence>
    <PartNumber>Product_H|||DAL|||CPCC05R2400JB32</PartNumber>
    <ParentGroupIdentifier>Combo Memory</ParentGroupIdentifier>
    <ManufacturerPartNumber>CPCC05R2400JB32</ManufacturerPartNumber>
    <Manufacturer>Spansion</Manufacturer>
</CatalogEntry>
</CatalogEntries>
```

is there anyway that I can customize the elements of output xml?

Thanks,
Harish M

Comment: I resolved this issue by involving XSLT once the Marshalling is done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the tag in XML using JAXB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18605340/how-to-remove-the-tag-in-xml-using-jaxb)